# $p$-localization and $p$-completion of a finite group coincide.

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, abelian-groups

My question has to do with that post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215467/p-local-space-vs-p-completion. Here the guy who posted the answer asserts that when $\pi_{*}X$ is finite (or more generally finitely generated), then the $p$-localization agrees with the $p$-completion. How could someone prove this?

Because it might be easier for someone to answer if they now what's my background roughly, here is a quick summary:

Since $\pi_{*}X$ is always abelian ($* \geq 2$), the $p$-localization for me is just the morphism $\pi_{*}X \to L_K(\pi_{*}X)$, where $K=\oplus_{p \in J} \mathbb{Z}/p$, $J=P-\{p\}$ and $P$ the set of all primes, while the $p$-completion of the abelian group $\pi_{*}X$ is just the inverse limit, $\varprojlim_{r \geq 1} \pi_{*}X/p^r \pi_{*}X$.

As far as I know regardless if an abelian group $A$ is finitely generated or not, the $\oplus_{p \in J} \mathbb{Z}/p$-localization over an arbitrary set of primes $J$ always exists and is the morphism
$$ A \to A \otimes \mathbb{Z}[J^{-1}].$$
On the other hand regarding the completion, the finitely generated assumption seems more crucial, since when it is fulfilled the $p$-completion coincides with the localization $L_{\mathbb{Z}[1/p]}A$. Therefore here is where I start becoming confused. How these two things are related and why?

Comment: I don't think they say it's true that localization and completion agree for finitely generated abelian groups, because that is false (they do not agree for $\Bbb Z$). For a finite abelian group you can verify without too much difficulty that completion / localization at a prime $p$ is a quotient map (killing off the terms prime to $p$) by verifying this for $\Bbb Z/q$, $q$ a prime power, and observing that every finite abelian group is a direct sum of these.

Comment: @MikeMiller thanks for the feedback, because am not very familiar with these ideas (I still try to understand them) could you please write out the two maps (completion and localization) for the finite case?

Comment: In fact, I understand the localization map, because $\mathbb{Z}_{p^r} \otimes \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=\mathbb{Z}_{p^r}$. How about the $p$-completion though?